# Install Postgis in Ubuntu 16.04 in with already postgresql 9.3 installed

Tags: postgresql, postgis, ubuntu-16.04

In ubuntu 16.04 when I tried to install postgis with using **apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1** this command, it installed postgresql 9.6 and postgis-9.6 version. And when tried to create extension it gives error **ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory**.

```
postgres@db:~$ psql
psql (9.6.3, server 9.3.17)
Type "help" for help.
```

Comment: This is not a programming questions. Try here https://askubuntu.com/ or here https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't use `sudo` before `apt-get` which is causing issue with write permissions of your directory.

To prevent this error `remove` the installed version and `reinstall` it  with `sudo` like,

```
sudo apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

[Read more](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71302/error-when-trying-to-run-create-extension-postgis) related with your issue and follow the [steps](https://gist.github.com/mdiener21/4ea94d50f1260bee39647d99517f6e9d) to install specific version.